# How can we know what is mundane?

Tags: path

How can we know what is mundane? Mundane life contains many components that superficially overlap with the Buddhist path:

- religious belief
- unusual experiences
- changes to character
- epiphanies
- etc.

Aside from taking a poll of monks or devout Buddhists, is there **a means to test** whether we have made any progress?

Comment: i quite like the reply *it doesn't matter*, and hope someone answers that way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you are, at least, a Sotapanna, **everything** you experience is mundane.

Comment: i can't stress enough that this *seems to have dissolved* all my sad questions about the "path". thanks!

Comment: i hope that the edit is fine. i liked the answer very much as it is, but i don't want to confuse anyone with its typo or declamation haha. all the best, and thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Pali Buddhism, what is not mundane is defined by the word '*lokuttara*', which means '*beyond the world*', '*supramundane*' or '*transcendent*" &, most importantly, equates with the realisation of '*emptiness*' ('*sunnata*'), '*not-self*' ('*anatta*') or selflessness. To quote:

> *Ye te suttantā tathāgatabhāsitā gambhīrā gambhīratthā **lokuttarā** **suññata**paṭisaṃyuttā*
>
> *We will listen when discourses that are words of the Tathagata — deep, deep in their meaning, **transcendent**, connected with **emptiness**...*
>
> [*SN 20.7*](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn20/sn20.007.than.html)

Therefore, unless the mind is, at least, Sotapanna, everything experienced is 'mundane'.

---

Contrary to the above, what is '*mundane*' in Pali Buddhism is described as follows:

> *What is right view affected by the taints, partaking of merit, ripening in the acquisitions?*
>
> *There is what is given and what is offered and what is sacrificed; there is fruit and result of good and bad actions (kamma); there is this world and the other world (paraloka); there is mother and father; there are beings who are reborn spontaneously (sattā opapātikā); there are in the world good and virtuous recluses and brahmins (samaṇabrāhmaṇāsamaṇa) who have realised for themselves by direct knowledge and declare this world & the other world.*
>
> [*MN 117*](https://suttacentral.net/en/mn117)

Therefore, included with the ordinary world of common conventions, the following Buddhist topics are also 'mundane':

- Kamma & rebirth
- Other worlds
- Blind faith in words of teachers & gurus